# Grails return uploaded file in form from command object

Tags: grails

Is there a way to return uploaded file in form?

Usually I would upload file in my form. But when the validation is triggered, such as command object, I can return the input (text, date) fields but I cant return the uploaded file. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: can I do it with session? store the uploaded file in session and return it in view?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `MultipartFile` property in your command object class.

Comment: FYI... We have a whole article about this at http://guides.grails.org/grails-upload-file/guide/index.html.